Handling running processes when main program is killed
I have an application using Tomcat which executes some other java programs. The different java programs are passed to the main application as argument.
The main program is using org.apache.commons.exec.DefaultExecutor and org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteWatchDog.
When the main application is killed using "kill -9", the invoked programs are dangling which is a problem. I need to terminate all the invoked programs before the main program is killed.
I read about shutdown hook but then that is applicable for graceful shutdown. Any suggestion as to what can be a solution?

Solution: have you considered not using SIGKILL? it literally does not allow the application to gracefully shutdown. Use anything else like SIGTERM or SIGINT. https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=management-process-termination

There is no safe way to kill child threads.
Read the answers in the linked stream: Is there a good way to forcefully stop a Java thread?


I need to terminate all the invoked programs before the main program is killed.

You simply cannot.  The application is forcibly killed by the OS, so the main program ceases to execute.

I read about shutdown hook but then that is applicable for graceful shutdown
This is correct.  kill -9 is not a graceful shutdown.

I can think of 3 ways you can do this:

Inside each externally running process, you periodically poll to see if the parent process is still alive.  Discounting any solution that relies on the parent process doing something as it exits (e.g. removing/adding a file), you otherwise could:

Have the child repeatedly look in the operation system process list (e.g. ps) and see if the parent is still there. (Parent must give the child the parent's PID)
Have the parent process open a socket/port similar and the child process repeatedly checks it is still open. (Parent must give the child the address of this)
Have the parent process periodically write to a file to indicate it is alive.  Child process repeatedly inspects timestamp of this semaphore file. (Parent must give the child the path of this)


If you cannot alter the java programs, then you create an intermediate application whose job is to manage the java child processes.  This needs to monitor the parent (in the ways described above), and if the parent disappears then terminate the java child processes. But this intermediate monitor is vulnerable to the kill -9 treatment too.
Use an Operating System specific feature that will ensure child processes are cleaned up by the OS itself.  For that, read here: How to make child process die after parent exits?


This is how it was handled

the main program spans a separate process with its own specific timeout parameter. The org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteWatchDog attempts to kill the separate process after its timeout is over
main program dies or the child process does not terminate.
Run a separate task periodically which kind of uses some shared data (in my case mongodb) with the main program and tracks if there are dangling processes. If there are then it kills such processes. If it cannot kill the dangling process, it sends an alert after a threshold count is breached and at that time we manually check the issue.

